# Hibernate named query

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I'm trying to fetch a set of results between two dates 
Using HQL

```
@NamedQuery( 
           name = "getAppointmentsByDateWeek",
           query = "select a from Appointment a where a.appointmentDate BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 "
           ),
```

however the named parameter's do not work and I am unsure on how to set the correctly

Comment: what do you mean? Are you setting the parameters correctly?

Comment: @Paplusc I think you are allowed to write a select like that in HQL, it's not wrong

Comment: @vc73 I want to be able to select it between two dates, My orginal HQL for selecting a certain date works like`select a from Appointment a where a.appointmentDate = :date` I want to be able to select all the appointments with the date between two set dates. but it won't set it like this

Comment: so you're saying that writing something like: `session.createNamedQuery("getAppointmentsByDateWeek").setParameter("date1",//yourdate).setParameter("date2",//yourdate).getResultList()` doesn't work?

Comment: @vc73 Yeah it doesn't allow me to set the parameters throws a type error

Comment: what kind of type error? Are you putting a Date object or a Timestamp?